# have setup teamcity CI in gitlab ,when a build is triggered do we have an option to know wheather its started by webhook or vcs polling

Tags: gitlab, teamcity, webhooks

how can we know a build has been started by webhook or vcs polling in teamcity .repo is stored in gitlab and teamcity is CI tool.earlier we were building using the VCS polling ,now added teamcity CI integration like shown in the screeshot,how to know my integration with teamcity is working
[image: teamcity CI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on particular `build -> Overview`

There is label called `Triggered by:`

if it was triggered by user then **"username"** is appears otherwise **"VCS Trigger"** or **"Schedule Trigger**" is written.

Comment: thanks abut that ,can i have a gitlab webhook which can hit the teamcity,each time a commit change occurs. http://teamcity.int:8080/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/commitHookNotification?locator=vcsRoot:(id:$vcsrootId) but hitting a 401 :
Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 401 Authentication required To login manually go to "/login.html" page